# Invalid Identifier on Sql left join oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, left-join

Hi I got some problems with the following Query

```
SELECT *
FROM PARTNER P
     , ADDRESS A
     ,DOSSIERPARTNERRELATIONSHIP DPR
   LEFT JOIN PARTNERHIST PH ON P.ID=PH.PARTNER_ID
WHERE (P.NAME ='Burger' OR PH.NAME='Burger')
 AND P.ID = DPR.PARTNER_ID
 AND A.PARTNER_ID = P.ID
 ;
```

when I'm trying to execute it I got the following error:

> ORA-00904: "P"."ID": invalid identifier

Also when I'm trying the following I got the same error

```
SELECT *
FROM PARTNER P
     , ADDRESS A
     ,DOSSIERPARTNERRELATIONSHIP DPR
   LEFT JOIN PARTNERHIST PH ON PARTNER.ID= PH.PARTNER_ID
WHERE (P.NAME ='Burger' OR PH.NAME='Burger')
 AND P.ID = DPR.PARTNER_ID
 AND A.PARTNER_ID = P.ID
 ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM PARTNER P
INNER JOIN ADDRESS A ON A.PARTNER_ID = P.ID
INNER JOIN DOSSIERPARTNERRELATIONSHIP DPR ON P.ID = DPR.PARTNER_ID
LEFT JOIN PARTNERHIST PH ON P.ID= PH.PARTNER_ID
WHERE (P.NAME ='Burger' OR PH.NAME='Burger')
```

Comment: @SaharshShah any url or reference to these standards?